# Resize ImageView depending on screen size - Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

Is there an easy way to resize an ImageView easily depending on screen size. I can't use drawables on this one so it is a bit more difficult for me. I need the tablet size to be around 117px by 56px whereas I need a phone size to be 41px by 57px. I know that things like using sp won't work as that is for text and so on but I am unable to work out a way to do this. Ignore the source image I am using as that is just for working out size on the Preview. When this is done it won't have a android:src.

Code for ImageView:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"      
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <ImageView     
        android:id="@+id/list_image"   
        android:layout_width="41sp"
        android:layout_height="57sp"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a LinearLayout with weights. And as a child the ImageView with "match_parent" and adjustViewBounds=true and scaleType="centerCrop"? Hope i get the point...